Does this End Times timeline correspond to any known suppositions?
I have created the following end times timeline of the 7 years tribulation:
In year 1:
● Antichrist makes covenant with many for 7 years (Daniel 9:27);
From year 1 to year 3.5:
● Beginning of sorrows (wars, famines, pestilences, earthquakes etc.);
In year 3.5:
● Abomination of desolation;
● The Antichrist becomes the ruler of the world;
● Christians go to the wilderness;
From year 3.5 to year 7:
● The Great Tribulation;
● The false prophet makes the world population to receive the mark of the beast;
● The false prophet creates the image of the beast;
● The false prophet makes the world population to worship the beast;
● War with the saints;
In year 7:
● Rapture;
Are there any End Times theorists see it playing out similar to this?

I am afraid unless you scope this by adding more context, it may be closed as being opinionated.

Hi, we don't accept questions that are just asking for opinion on anyone's ideas. I edited the question in a way that may be answerable in a definite way.  Basically, it comes down to answers have to be supported by citations.  So you'd have to find a well-known branch of Christianity or scholars who support your ideas to answer it.

I’m voting to close this question because the OP seems to be seeking confirmation that his personal timeline can be authenticated by finding another one that matches it. It boils down to personal opinions perhaps even confirmation bias.

@ Anonymous User - The outline listed is quite similar to the Dispensational Scheme of John Darby (1830) adopted by several modern denominations.  Although there are many flaws in it, this is well-known and taught by many modern Evangelicals, sans Mainline traditional Churches.  So it is appropriate that you call it "suppositions."

Here's how one denomination depticts it.
[Infographic]: Timeline of End Time Events | United Church of God


The book of Revelation describes Satan's wrath on God's people and God's judgment on humanity as seven seals. Additional passages in Matthew, Daniel and other books add further detail. By piecing together all of these references, we can create a timeline of end-time events, presented here. Feel free to print this chart and stow it in your Bible for reference.

Full details are in their booklet, The Rapture vs. the Bible | United Church of God
